# How to map Native query result to Entity class which is not a part of actual entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Entity class named loginlog (which refers to loginlog table in my mysql) which has only two properties one is user id and the other one is datetime.
I am trying to get count of logins in a day for each user. My query returns with 2 columns which are user id and count. As count is not a property of entity class how would i map the result from query ? I can do it with POJO class but i have so many queries which is of similar nature. I have to create so many classes if i go with POJOs.

Is there any better way to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to return ***THE NUMBER OF USERS*** only in one column. 
So try this Query : `select COUNT(l.id) from loginlog l where l.id = :id`

and **:id** is for the specific user you want to count his number of logins.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `List<Object[]>` from your Repository. For example if your select is like this: `SELECT id, count(*) FROM ...` the first element in the Object array will be the id and the second the count.

Comment: can i get column names in Object[]?

Comment: I don't think so. You just map the columns by selection order.